# A set has the property that $A\subset B$ holds for any set $B$. Prove that $A=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

- A set has the property that $A\subset B$ holds for any set $B$. Prove that $A=\emptyset$.

In the question, do we know that empty set is  subset of for all set? If yes, then the question is clear. But, if no, then how can I prove? Can you help, hint?

Comment: Consider $B=\varnothing$.

Comment: You might want to also define "subset".

Comment: Why did you 'close' vote?

Comment: A point on notation: $A\subset B$ often implies that $A\neq B$.

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set

Answer (score 2):

Assume that there is $a\in A$ then, by hypothesis, taking $B=A\setminus\{a\}$, we have that
$$A\subset A\setminus\{a\}\implies a\in A\setminus\{a\}.$$
Contradiction.

P.S. If we assume that the property 
"$A$ set has the property that $A\subset B$ holds for any set $B\not=\emptyset$" holds then it implies that $A=\emptyset$ if the universal set contains at least two elements.
Note that if $a\in A$ and $A\not=\{a\}$ then take $B=A\setminus\{a\}\not=\emptyset$ and we have a contradiction (see above). If $A=\{a\}$ then take $B=A^c\not=\emptyset$ and $A\subset A^c$ gives you again a  contradiction.

Comment: @Kahler I wonder if my P.S. answer your question which is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a set such that $A\subset B$ for any arbitrary set $B$. What do you get for the choice of $B=\emptyset$?

Comment: If $B=\emptyset$ then $A$ must be empty set.

Answer (score 1):

For any set B, we are given that A ⊂ B. Assume B = ∅ to show a contradiction.

A ⊂ ∅ means x ∈ A ⟹ x ∈ ∅, which is false.

If you reference the truth table for implication, the only way this would imply true is if x ∈ A is False. So if x is not an element of A then x = ∅.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the empty set is a subset of every set. (You said the answer is clear if this is the case.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof that takes into account the standard understanding of $A\subset B$ (*i.e.*, where it is inferred that $A\neq B$):

We have $A\subset \{1\}$ and $A\subset \{2\}$, but this can only happen if $A=\emptyset$.